# Git flow: Should I pull and merge from destination branch before create a pull request?

Tags: git, merge, pull-request, git-flow

I want to know whether it is a good practice to merge my destination branch into mine **before** create a pull request.

*Example:*

develop
feature1 (created from develop)

develop (has new changes)
feature1 (development finished)

Should I `merge` from *develop* to *feature1* **before** create a `pull request` from *feature1* to *develop*?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best practice is to do a `rebase` before creating a pull request. This will make the history tree cleaner and easier to read for the develop branch.